# I wrote an if/elseif-statement but it only gives me the first answer, why?

Tags: c++, if-statement

So I am pretty new to C++, and I was playing around with the code. I was writing an if-statement that would check if you had written "yes" or "no" and then give you different answers based on that.

The problem I am having is that when I write down "no" it gives me the same answer as if I had written "yes"; "nice".

I am working with the console (MSDOS) and not an API, again I am pretty new to C++ and programming overall and that is probably why I can't get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
string happy;

getline(cin, happy);

if(happy == "yes" || "Yes")
{
    cout << "Nice" << endl;
}
else if(happy == "no" || "No")
{
    cout << "Not nice" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Alright..." << endl;
}
```

I have done my best to find out the answer and see if there is something wrong in the code, but I can't seem to find anything. Would be happy if you could help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(happy == "yes" || "Yes")
```

is wrong. Use

```
if(happy == "yes" || happy == "Yes")
```

instead. The following unfortunate series of events happen in your code: the compiler evaluates first `happy == "yes"`, which is a `bool` (either `true` or `false`), then ORs it with the C-string constant "Yes", which decays to a non-null pointer, and is convertible to `true`. At the end you get an OR between a `bool` and `true`, which is always true, bummer.

As a rule of thumb, always compile your program with all warnings turned on: for gcc, I usually use `-Wall -Wextra`. Such things will probably be caught at compile time, so you can at least start wandering why the warning.

**EDIT** Funny enough, neither gcc nor clang warn anything about your code. Of course they are not required, but will be nice if they do.

Comment: Dumb dumb, I didn't notice it was yes and Yes :(

Answer (score 0):

This should work, try this:

```
string happy;

getline(cin, happy);

if(happy == "yes" || happy == "Yes")
{
    cout << "Nice" << endl;
}
else if(happy == "no" || happy == "No")
{
    cout << "Not nice" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Alright..." << endl;
}
```